# Translation help needed from SWIFT to Objective C "healthStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes"

Tags: objective-c, swift, healthkit

Unfortunately Apple do not translate their new examples to Objective C. I have a working SWIFT code fragment, but my translation to objective C is not working - The authorisation request does not appear in the objective c code on the iPhone -

SWIFT:

```
   class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

   let healthStore = HKHealthStore()


    override func willActivate() {
       super.willActivate()

       guard let quantityType = HKQuantityType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate) else {
            return
       }

       let dataTypes = Set(arrayLiteral: quantityType)
       healthStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(nil, readTypes: dataTypes) { (success, error) -> Void in
           if success == false {

           }
       }
    }

   }
```

Objective-C:

```
@interface InterfaceController()

@property HKHealthStore * healthScore;

@end


@implementation InterfaceController


- (void)willActivate {

[super willActivate];

NSString * quantity = HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate;

HKQuantityType * quantityType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:quantity];

NSSet <HKQuantityType *> * dataTypes = [NSSet setWithArray:@[quantityType]];

[self.healthScore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:nil readTypes:dataTypes completion:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
if (!success) { } }];
}

@end
```

Comment: By "not working", what do you mean? Doesn't compile? Doesn't successfully complete the authorization? You might need to narrow this down.

Comment: The authorisation request does not appear in the objective c code on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing creating `healthScore` prior to using it.

`let healthStore = HKHealthStore()` creates an instance.

```
// Missing initialization
self.healthScore = [HKHealthStore new];

...

[self.healthScore requestAuthorizationToShareTypes:nil readTypes:dataTypes completion:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
```